# Find adjacent cells in a grid stored in array (not multidimensional)

Tags: arrays, grid

I have an array [0... to 24] which is a 5x5 grid. Given one index, I need to find the 8 adjacent cells (their indexes). The problem is that, in edge cases, it goes over the other side.

For example, index 12 (the middle one) is

```
top-left:     12 - grid size+1 => 6
top:          12 - grid size   => 7
top-right:    12 - grid size-1 => 8
left:         12 - 1           => 11
right:        12 + 1           => 13
bottom-left:  12 + grid size-1 => 16
bottom:       12 + grid size   => 17
bottom-right: 12 + grid size+1 => 18
```

But if I try the same with the "10" for example, the left one (10-1) gives me 9 which is one row above.

Is there any way to get the adjacents without using a 2d array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I figured it out (though I don't know if it's the best way):

```
function getAdjacents(i, gridSize){
  var mod = i%gridSize;
  var adjacents = {
    topLeft: mod == 0 || i < gridSize ? null : i- (gridSize + 1),
    top: i < gridSize ? null : i-gridSize,
    topRight: i < gridSize ||  mod == 4 ? null : i- (gridSize - 1),
    left: mod == 0 ? null : i-1,
    right: mod == 4 ? null : i+1,
    bottomLeft: mod == 0 || i >= (gridSize*gridSize-gridSize) ? null :  i + (gridSize-1),
    bottom: i >= (gridSize*gridSize-gridSize) ? null : i+gridSize,
    bottomRight: mod == 4 || i >= (gridSize*gridSize-gridSize) ? null :  i + (gridSize+1)
  }
  return adjacents;
}
```